# GeoPoint field type in elasticsearch-dsl-py

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm using `elasticsearch-dsl-py 0.0.11` for `ES 1.7` and I want to add a `GeoPoint` type as listed in `fields.py` :

```
__all__ = [
    'construct_field', 'Field', 'Object', 'Nested', 'Date', 'String', 'Float', 'Double',
    'Byte', 'Short', 'Integer', 'Long', 'Boolean', 'Ip', 'Attachment',
    'GeoPoint', 'GeoShape', 'InnerObjectWrapper'
]
```

But no class named `GeoPoint` exists and I cannot create a mapping for a location field like this:

```
location = GeoPoint()
```

What should I do?

Comment: The `GeoPoint` class has been explicitly defined as of Jan 1, 2017: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/commit/03fc51a954576519fee94f0cc5515c9ed1dd2cdf

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure to import `GeoPoint` like this

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import GeoPoint
```

Then you can declare your location field as

```
location = GeoPoint()
```

Comment: There is not any definition of a class called `GeoPoint` in `fields.py` or anywhere ( I searched in Github and nothing was found )

Comment: All classes are [generated dynamically](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/master/elasticsearch_dsl/field.py#L264) and are not contained in a statically defined class. Have you at least tried that code? It works for me, so I don't get why you're downvoting.

Comment: IDEs will have an issue with importing this class, but the code given by @Val does work.

Comment: How do I query for that?

Comment: nvm, it's `MyDocType.search().filter(
    'geo_distance', distance='1000m', location={"lat": "40", "lon": "-74"}
)`

Comment: This should be asked in another question so as not to mix too many concepts into a single question.